# [(ngModel)]="model.right" crashing angular inside of ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to get ng-bootstrap working with Angular 6, specifically the tabbed dialogs.

As soon as I bring the "buttons" into the tabbed dialogues, angular is crashing. It appears to be the [(ngModel)]="model.left" statement from the examples that's doing it.

The app compiles fine, but will not render into the browser.
No error messages appear in the console or the server console.

```
<label class="btn-primary" ngbButtonLabel>
<input type="checkbox" formControlName="left" ngbButton [(ngModel)]="model.left"> Left
</label>
</div>

=======================

Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 10.6.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 6.0.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.2.2
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

Comment: Is the `model` property defined ?

Comment: you shouldn't use ngmodel and formcontrolname together, but if you want you should mention ```[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"``` too.

Comment: I don't know if it's a copy/paste issue but in your code you have [(NgModel)] instead of [(ngModel)]

Comment: @MichaelDesigaud - error in the post not the code. Same issue. model property defined in the .ts file

Comment: @fatemefazli I have added this to the <input> selector - no difference unfortunately.

Comment: model property defined and initialized ?